# PhoneGap Developer App Download Error

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

I'm using the PhoneGap Developer App to instantly test my apps and since tonight the app says 'DOWNLOADING', and then a few seconds later is says 'DOWNLOAD ERROR'. After that, a popup appears saying

`Unable to download archive from the server. Please upgrade the PhoneGap CLI or check your network settings.`

So, how do I upgrade the PhoneGap CLI and what settings should I check? I haven't changed any network settings and the PhoneGap Developer App worked fine on my Macbook and iPhone, but now it says this.

What's the problem and how do I solve it?

**EDIT**
I now realise that this is happening now because the PhoneGap Developer App for iOS has been updated (now version 1.5.2). I've upgraded the PhoneGap CLI to version 5.0.0-0.28.0, which is the recommended version according to [this](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/05/20/pg_dev_app_1_5_2_release/) blog post from PhoneGap

Seems like there's something going wrong with the new way the Desktop and Mobile app now communicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THE SOLUTION:

Download the newest version of the PhoneGap Desktop App from the official website. So you have to update the PhoneGap Developer App for mobile, the PhoneGap CLI and download the newest PhoneGap Desktop App.

Comment: We have downloaded latest version of phonegap developer,but getting same error?

Comment: You have to update everything, so that means the app on your pc, the phonegap CLI and the app on your phone. Skipping one of these will result in the error you now get.

Comment: the solution not works for me...
am using windows 10

Answer (score 1):

For me starting the local server from PhoneGap CLI helped. The thing is that for some reason using the PhoneGap Desktop doesn't fire a special Windows dialog to permit some actions for the app.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to run manually in a cmd window the command `phonegap serve` to trigger the firewall request to open by Windows (if you are on Windows). You can also see the log. Leave the window open.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the port from 3000 to something else and it worked.
Probably had something else listening to it.

Answer (score 1):

While using WiFi, Your computer & device has to be on the same network.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and fixed it updating the phonegap.

Update your phonegap `npm update -g phonegap` or `sudo npm update -g phonegap` if root is required.

Also update your Phonegap CLI in your mobile.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the fix, at least for the Android App. Seems like Adobe has pushed out a broken update...

Comment: @fct hai,when i tried your code in cmd prompt,it shows `npm is not recognizing internal or external error `

Comment: mine doesn't work and i'm very sure that i have the latest version of CLI, Mobile App and Desktop App. Do you think it doesn't work because i use the mobile hotspot of my android to connect with my laptop and then host server on the laptop?

Answer (score 0):

I had to install  `node.js` and it's working now.